# How to Overlap table cells in HTML?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to overlap cells in a table.
Here's my code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma616776096433166-rkqhpj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

my .ts

```js
this.dataListDetail.forEach(x => {
  const col = this.header.findIndex(c => +c.value == x.day) - 1;
  const row = this.datalist.findIndex(c => c.No == x.num);
  for (let r = row; r < this.datalist.length; r++) {
    let cell = this.grid[r][col];
    if (cell.empty) {
      cell.rowspan = x.colspan_column;
      cell.desc = x.desc;
      cell.empty = false;
      for (let i = 1; i < x.colspan_column; i++) {
        this.grid[r + i][col].empty = false;
        this.grid[r + i][col].rowspan = 0;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

resulting in incorrect results:

[image]

The display result now should be fixed as follows:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: What's the difference between 2 images. They look the same to me. What am I missing?

Comment: I dont see any difference

Comment: Oh sorry, I add wrong img